# source Code for fixed device date and time

Tags: android, date, time

How to get correct Date and time for my application,when wrong android device date and time.need to source .
please help me.
thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You may need to use a custom NITZ or NTP Library**

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d5ce3bcfe17e272b?pli=1

So just a heads up that Android uses NITZ events provided by a carrier to properly set the system date and time. Android also falls-back to network NTP automatically when no cellular network is available.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NITZ

The time provided by currentTimeMillis() will typically be the best available time, and it's what all of the services on the device use, like Calendar and Alarm Clock.

However

However the NTP API isn't somewhere that Java code can access, which means we're back to using an existing Java NTP/SNTP client library if we want an accurate time regardless of whether we are on a network that is NITZ capable.

**Java NTP library**

You can find a naive implementation of a Java NTP Library from

support.ntp.org

Comment: thanx Vatsal Shah,but Java NTP is not support Sri Lanka :(

Comment: Ok. then let me check another thing which will work in Srilanka

Answer (score 0):

```
first you try to get the current time zone and then you get date and time of current time zone

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
Log.d("Time zone","="+tz.getDisplayName());



public String getTime(String timezone) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
    Date date = c.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String strDate = df.format(date);
    return c.getTime().toString();
}
```